# Y coordinate of PubKey on elliptic curve prefix

Tags: public-key, ecdsa

Public keys in the form of 04[x,y] can be compressed since the x axis is symmetrical. Hence we only need the x-coordinate with the 02/03 prefix which states if Y is odd or even. I don't understand the latter, are odd/even on an elliptic curve the same as pos/neg on a Cartesian plain? This makes sense since negative integers can't be expressed in keys. So would the 'negative' Y-coordinate correspond to an 'odd' (03 prefix). If so, how are these coordinates differ in odd/even if the x axis is symmetrical?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no.

The X and Y coordinates of points on the secp256k1 curve are integers modulo *p = 2<sup>256</sup> - 2<sup>32</sup> - 977*. Positive/negative don't exist there, as modulo *p* it holds for every *a* that *-a = p-a*.

So, we need another criterion to distinguish the two solutions for *y* for the equation *y<sup>2</sup> = x<sup>3</sup> + 7*.

There are a number of possibilities:

- **High/low**: we could simply distinguish them based on whether they are below/above *p/2*. If *a < p/2, then its "negation" *p-a* will be *> p/2*. As *p* is odd, no point is equal to *p/2* itself.
- **Even/odd**: what the standard picked is looking at the parity of *a* when brough to range *[0, p)*. Because *p* is odd, negating any number except *0* will change its parity. And it can be shown that no solutions for *y=0* exist.
- A third possibility is using **quadratic residuosity** as a tie-breaker. It turns out that of the two solutions for *y*, one will always be a square modulo *p*, and the other won't be. This is perhaps most similar to solutions in the real numbers and their sign: the postive numbers in R, just like the quadratic residues mod *p*, have a square root - and their negations don't.

So yes, it is somewhat like positive/negative for real solutions, but that "somewhat" is just a property that is true for half the domain, and which is complemented when negating the coordinate.

Comment: Thanks Pieter! To fully digest that i will need to learn some more EC arithmetic. Also, how does the modulo function work here? So are the number of possible points on secp256k1 the remainder of y^2 = x^3 + 7 divided by p = a large proven prime less than 2^256?

Comment: The curve consists of all points *(x,y)* for which *y^2 = x^3 + 7 (mod p)*, or in other words: *y^2 - x^3 - 7* is a multiple of *p*. And yes, *p = 2^256 - 2^32 - 977* is a prime number.

Comment: The number of points satisfying such an equation was an unsolved problem for a long time, but since 1985 a reasonably efficient algorithm exists: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schoof%27s_algorithm (warning: not easy). Without this, elliptic curve cryptography wouldn't be possible.

Comment: Fascinating, thanks again!